# Upload notification

Tags: php, javascript

I am using EFUMultiple Uploader to receive files on my site. Does anyone know of a tutorial that will teach me how I can be notified each time there is a new file or batch of files in my uploads folder?

Answer (score 0):

It will become annoying, fast, I can promise you that.

But either way, in your upload script, you'll want to use either the [mail()](http://php.net/mail) function or, for example the [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) library if you don't have a SMTP server configured on your PHP installation.

Comment: Thanks David, I will look at the problem properly after some sleep and let you know if I succeed. My brain is already fried from a busy day :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this (untested) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// Warning: this script and UPLOADED_FILES_DB, for security reasons, should not be in UPLOAD_PATH.
define('UPLOAD_PATH', '...');
define('UPLOADED_FILES_DB', 'uploaded_files');

define('MAIL_TO', 'you@example.com');
define('MAIL_FROM', 'cron@example.com');
define('MAIL_SUBJECT', 'Uploaded files');

// Get old files:
if (file_exists(UPLOADED_FILES_DB)) {
    $old_files = unserialize(file_get_contents(UPLOADED_FILES_DB));
} else {
    $old_files = array();
}

// Get current files:
$current_files = array();
foreach (new DirectoryIterator(UPLOAD_PATH) as $file_info) {
    if (!$file_info->isDot()) {
        $current_files[$file_info->getFilename()] = filemtime($file_info->getFilename());
    }
}

// Update database:
file_put_contents(serialize($current_files), UPLOADED_FILES_DB);

// Compute differences:
$added_files = array_diff(array_keys($old_files), array_keys($current_files));
$removed_files = array_diff(array_keys($current_files), array_keys($old_files));
$changed_files = array_diff_assoc($old_files, $current_files);

// Send message:
$headers = 'From: ' . MAIL_FROM . "\r\n";
$message = 'Added files: ' . implode(', ', $added_files);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Then you would put that script on a cron job to execute every day or so, or you can `include` it in wherever your upload code is — though, the latter approach would get annoying quickly.